# How can I get all of the visited urls visited in a chrome extension background page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create an extension that will (simply) access every url the user views, the larger scope of the project is browser history across multiple computers/browsers for easier browsing history search but that is irrelevant here. My current code will read the url Sometimes, but not every page:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status == "loading"){ 
            //process url
    }
});
```

How can I get this code to read every single url in multiple tabs? I am doing this in a background page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a content script that runs on every page and sends a message to the background page with the value of location.href. You can use [chrome.extension.sendMessage()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) for this.